# PreparedStatement.executeUpdate() not affecting database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

I want to insert values into a database table. The table has two columns: id and image. The id is an auto-increment int and the image is a blob type. Here is my code:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    File imgfile = new File(request.getParameter("img"));
    InputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile);
    PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("insert into pictures (image) values(?)");
    pre.setBinaryStream(1, fin, imgfile.length());
    int done=pre.executeUpdate();
} catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I check the database and nothing inserted. Server Output:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for
>   column 'image' at row 1

Comment: pretty certain a `SQLException` is raised and ignored by you.

Comment: changed it and found the exception

Comment: How you have defined the column? Is it a blob?

Comment: it is a blob, column size 65535 if that helps

Comment: Data too long - probably means that your definition of column1 isn't right.

Comment: What is length of image file?

Comment: 65.2 KB (66,795 bytes)

Comment: 65535 is not enough to store your image (that is the most probable reason).

Comment: so how do I fix it?

Comment: Analyze the sizes of all images that could be stored in DB, and change the size of col1 to appropriate size.

Comment: Use `LONGBLOB` (or maybe `MEDIUMBLOB`), not `BLOB`.

Comment: Beside that, you can always transform the picture, or image to desired size, but, you'll find your own way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I changed the data type of the `image` column from `blob` to `longblob` Thanks.